# Traverse a custom html string with Jquery

Tags: jquery, traversal

I am not able to traverse a custom html string with Jquery, like in this example:

```
html = '<a href="http://www.site.com"><img width="800" src="http://www.site.com/pic.jpg" alt="" /></a><br /><br />Description<br />';
found = $(html).find("a").length;
```

"found" returns 0, while I would expect to get 1

I suspect I'm doing something really stupid here, but after hours I still don't see what's wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to put your HTML code into a “root element” like a DIV:

```
$("<div>"+html+"</div>").find("a").length
```